# <iframe> y read as '&lt;' inside noscript tag

Tags: django, iframe, django-templates, google-tag-manager, noscript

I'm adding *Google Tag Manager* to a website but I'm getting something unusual. I add the code like this:

```
{% if not debug %}
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-CODE"
                      height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
        </iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-CODE');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
{% endif %}
```

But when I inspect the code in Chrome browser I see this:

```
<noscript>&lt;iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/...sibility:hidden"&gt; &lt;/iframe&gt;</noscript>
```

In old versions I added *Google analytics* and *Crazy Egg* without problems. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a bug in Chrome, and all Chromium based browsers documented [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495151).

The solution described there is:

- 1. Open a page which has html tags inside  tag and JavaScript is enabled
- 2. Disabled javascript
- 3. Reload the page once. You will notice that HTML content inside  tag will be rendered as plain text. Chrome does not
     interpret html tags.